# Knockout observable subscription fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable subscription inside a function that reiterates on certain events:

```
ko.computed(function() {
   alert('computed fired'); 

   self.obs2.subscribe(function() {
      alert('subscribe fired');
   });

   return self.obs1();
});
```

I noticed that when that function runs, the code inside the subscription isn't executed, but when the subscription finally fires, the code inside it runs as many times as the reiterating function ran before it fired.

It was too complex to reproduce in JSfiddle, so I settled for a simpler, but similar example using a subscription inside a `computed` observable:

http://jsfiddle.net/norbiu/7hGNb/

1. Clicking on 'Edit Obs2' a few times will cause the alert to fire each time
2. Clicking on 'Edit Obs1' a few times will cause the first alert to fire, not the one inside the subscription
3. Clicking on 'Edit Obs2' once will cause the alert inside the subscription to run multiple times.

Is there a way to make the subscription run just once without having to move it outside the reiterating?

Comment: Your sample is oversimplified. Why do you need to subscribe inside a computed? What are you try to achieve? Because the only solution is to move the subscription outside of the computed what you don't want to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will subscribe on your `obs2` as many times are your `computed` evaluates.

I have no idea what do you want to achieve with subscribing on a different property inside a computed. I'm quite sure that there is a more proper solution exist to your use case...

However one possible workaround is to store the returned `subscription` object when calling `subscribe` and if there is an already stored `subscription` exists dispose it before subscribing again on your `obs2`:

```
self.subscription = null;

ko.computed(function() {
    alert('computed fired');

    if (self.subscription)
        self.subscription.dispose();

    self.subscription = self.obs2.subscribe(function() {
        alert('subscribe fired');
    });

    return self.obs1();
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42ggt/).